# Query speed in mysql

Tags: mysql

using Mysql as database and Python as front end. Have a scenario to join 500 000 records table with another
dynamically generated another table with around 50 000 records table.

The query is running slow and is getting time out.
How to improve the query performance?

```
SELECT 
    t1.column1,
    t2.column2 
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON 
    t1.column3 = t2.column3 AND 
    t1.column4 = t2.column4 AND 
    t1.column5 = t2.column5 AND 
    t1.column6 = t2.column6 AND 
    t1.column7 = t2.column7 
WHERE 
    t1.userID = 10 AND 
    t1.column8 = 0 AND 
    t1.column9 = 1
```

Comment: Where is the query?

Comment: Query + table structure (with indexes) + execution plan. That's how we can solve perf issues.

Comment: SELECT t1.column1,t2.column2 FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.coulmn3 = t2.coulmn3
AND t1.coulmn4 = t2.coulmn4
AND t1.coulmn5 = t2.coulmn5 AND t1.coulmn6 = t2.coulmn6
AND t1.coulmn7 = t2.coulmn7 WHERE t1.userID = 10 AND t1.coulmn8 = 0 AND t1.coulmn9 = 1

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, based on brief provided, I would have an index on your

```
Table1 on ( userID, Column8, Column9 )
Table2 on ( column3, column4, column5, column6, column7 )
```

The first table index will help optimize the retrieval of records on the WHERE.
Since table 1 is the primary driving the query, the table2 indexes will optimize the JOIN criteria.

Comment: @user40991 Could you post A) EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT …;, B) SHOW CREATE TABLE table1; C) SHOW CREATE TABLE table2:  D) SHOW INDEX FROM table1; and E) SHOW INDEX FROM table2, please.  Thanks